# When does an Android Singleton get destroyed?

Tags: java, android, singleton

Will a Singleton survive even if the activity is totally destroyed? I have some references to the Android Location Managers which call services to do GPS stuff, it works fine for an hour or two (Even with the app minimized and the screen is turned off) but after some time the updates will stop pinging, I have looked over some other Stack Overflow threads and I have seen conflicting responses about whether a Singleton will stay active or if it will be destroyed if the system needs memory.

If a Singleton is not a good way to keep a reference for a long period of time, what is the alternative?

Comment: it is a singleton. Its lifetime span is the one of the process

Answer (score 1):

A singleton's life depends on with what you initialize it. You can initialize it with your Activity which will only keep it active as long as the Activity is there.

To keep it on an application level, instantiate the Singleton with your `Application Context` instead of `Activity Context`

**UPDATE**

Alternative is using SQLite DB (first priority) or SharedPreferences (Throws Memory Exception if storing a lot of data).

If you want to use some data throughout a single launch, then Singleton method is easy and convenient.

Comment: Can you simply extend the Application class for the Singleton? Or do you have to create an Application class then put your Singleton inside that? The reason why I do not use a DB is because it's storing references to classes that aren't necessarily data only.

Comment: I create an Application class, put the Singleton in it and add this class to the Manifest. Job Done :D

Comment: What conditions will the Application class data still be destroyed? Only when the app process is destroyed? Or can it still be destroyed to free memory?

Answer (score 1):

Every app is started stoped in something similar as an OSGi container, 
when the app is started, then the static values are created, when you call the getInstance will occurs the same, once the app.onDestroy is called all memory is released and there fore the singletone destroyed...